# method onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver never gets called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an app in which I'm trying to register a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for intent of this type: `android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON` but the problem is that my onReceive() method never gets called!

This is how I did:

in `onCreate()` I've also tried to register this in `onResume()` but with the same result:

```
drb=new Adisor();
        IntentFilter intent=new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON");
        registerReceiver(drb,intent);
```

and my class `Adisor`:

```
  public class Adisor extends BroadcastReceiver {

               @Override
               public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   System.out.println("Bau");
                   if (intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT) != null) {
                   // prevent the camera app from opening
                   abortBroadcast();
                   System.out.println("HEY");
               //    mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
                   }
               }

            }
```

And I have the following permissions in the `manifest file`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

But when I press the camera button no message is displayed in the logcat!Any idea why?

EDIT: I also tried registering my intent in manifest file

```
  <activity android:name=".TakePhoto"
       >
<receiver android:name="com.Contest.Adisor"
           android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
           </intent-filter>
         </receiver>

Adisor is an inner class of `TakePhoto`.
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you pressing hardware camera button or software button? It is called only when the hardware camera button is pressed, not with the button in the camera application.

**EDIT**
Also, just found this:
[android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON not broadcasting on Desire Z (Froyo)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775406/android-intent-action-camera-button-not-broadcasting-on-desire-z-froyo)

> There is no requirement for a device manufacturer to send any
>   broadcast when the CAMERA button is clicked, from my reading of the
>   Compatibility Definition Document. It might only be used by the
>   foreground activity on the Desire Z. I don't have a Z and so cannot
>   confirm your tests.
>
> Since the vast majority of Android devices do not have a CAMERA button
>   at all, you will need to ensure that your app works well without such
>   a button, and that you advise users that the CAMERA button may or may
>   not work with your app depending upon device.

Comment: I press the hardware button, physical one which opens the camera!

Comment: please help me...cause this is not working:|.And I really need to do this right away!

Comment: @george I just updated my answer. Your code seems correct otherwise

Comment: I know.I think the phone is to blame cause I tried many versions.Thank u.Greetings from Romania!

Comment: Hey, referenced thread was my issue, as the quoted part says, there are no requirements... it works on G1, it does not on Desire Z. You need to reconsider target devices/functionality.

Comment: what do u mean by that?what reconsider target functionality means?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter =
    new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
registerReceiver(drb, intentFilter);
```

### Edited code.

Replace the following code portion.

```
public class Adisor extends BroadcastReceiver {

                       @Override
                       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                           System.out.println("Bau");
                           if (intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT) != null) {
                           // prevent the camera app from opening
                           abortBroadcast();
                           System.out.println("HEY");
                       //    mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
                           }
                       }

     }
```

with this.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver drb = new BroadcastReceiver() {


                      @Override
                       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                           System.out.println("Bau");
                           if (intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT) != null) {
                           // prevent the camera app from opening
                           abortBroadcast();
                           System.out.println("HEY");
                       //    mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
                           }
                       }
};
```

Comment: I did what u said but with the same result!!!!I've also tried registering in manifest as u see in my EDIT of my question.Here is my full code http://pastebin.com/USCvrji5

Comment: register your receiver in onCreate() and unregister in onDestroy().

Comment: Actually I registered it in onResume() and unregistered it in onPause()....but still not working....I don't know what's the problem!!

Comment: so please review your whole code again.It should work.Also check that you did not put your receiver code inside any method.

Comment: How should I put my receive code in some method?!I don't understand?!!

Comment: This is all I have related to this action: http://pastebin.com/LeSSqqAj please tell me what method are u talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change following  changes in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".TakePhoto">
    <receiver android:name="com.Contest.TakePhoto$Adisor"
               android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
               <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
               </intent-filter>
             </receiver>
```

Because you had declare broadcast receiver inside your activity TakePhoto