# BroadcastReceiver don't receive keypress on Camera button

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-camera, broadcast

I am trying to play some tone when my application is in background and I press on "***Camera***" button for that I am doing this simple steps.

1. Creating `BroadcastReceiver` class

   ```
   public class CameraButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           ToneGenerator tone = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF, 100);
           tone.startTone(0,2000);
           abortBroadcast();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register `BrodcastReceiver` in `onCreate` methode.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       MediaButtonBrodcastReceiver receiver = new MediaButtonBrodcastReceiver();        
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
       filter.setPriority(25645895);
       registerReceiver(receiver,filter);      
   }
   ```
3. Adding brodcast receiver to android manifest.

   ```
   <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name=".CameraButtonListener">
   <intent-filter android:priority="25645895">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```

After I launch my application, then press menu button and application goes to the background, after I press on Camera Button and nothing heppens, only camera application is opened. Maybe I am doing something wrong or I have missed something ?

I use Sony Ericsson XPeria Arc phone with Android 2.3.4 OS version.

Comment: Have you tried putting receiver in a service? Activities do not live long in the background, you can't expect it to receive signals once it no longer has the foreground...

Comment: @Joel I read some posts were people do something like this and thir code works good, I want to use Service in the end, if there was no way to do that in activity.

Comment: You need to do either #2 *or* #3, not both -- which is the right one depends on whether you only want to receive these events while the service is running or at any time. You might also consider using something other than a tone to determine whether or not it is getting control. Beyond that, bear in mind that it is possible that the device manufacturer for whatever device you are using happens to have their own app set with max priority on that `Intent`. Use the AppXplore app (on the Play Store) to examine the manifest of the device's camera app.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it nessary to use Service ? Or I can Use Activity ?

Comment: You can call `registerReceiver()` from either an `Activity` or a `Service`. The point is that you need to call `unregisterReceiver()` as well, and that the usefulness of the registered receiver is for the lifetime of the hosting component. For example, if you only want CAMERA button events while some activity of yours is in the foreground, use `registerReceiver()` from that activity. Bear in mind that CAMERA button behavior is somewhat up to the device manufacturer, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775406/android-intent-action-camera-button-not-broadcasting-on-desire-z-froyo

Comment: @CommonsWare i have download application AppXplore and there I press on camera I see:

Activities: com.sonyericsson.android.camera.CameraActivity
com.sonyericsson.android.camera.CameraActivityForCaptureOnly
com.sonyericsson.android.camera.ContactCoodinator
com.sonyericsson.android.camera.CreateShortcutActivity 

This mean that camara is used by other applications, and that's why I cant launch it ?

Comment: Using AppXplore, you can see if any of the `<receiver>` elements in Sony's camera app listen for `android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON`, and if so, what priority they have. And, as I mentioned in my previous comment, it is possible that they simply do not send the broadcast. And, since I would guess that less than 1% of Android devices have CAMERA buttons, IMHO you have already spent *way* more time on this than the feature is worth... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `<category>` element in your `<receiver>` element, if you are using step #3. That broadcast probably does not have a category -- you usually only see categories on `Intent` objects used for `startActivity()`.

Note that your step #2 does not specify a category with its `IntentFilter`, which is fine.

Comment: @CommonWare I think my phone have not support camera button, so I switch on Volume button, and its work, one more question, Can I receive volume down and up events when phone is sleeping ? Thanks a lot !!! you are the best !!!

Comment: here is my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248826/receive-volume-key-press-events-when-phone-is-in-deep-sleep

Answer (score 0):

Here, read up on [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).  Services are used if you want your application to keep performing tasks while in the background.  In this case, you want to know when something happens even if your application is not currently in the foreground.  This is how to do it.

Comment: You will need to do this if you want to be notified when your application is in the background.