# Receive volume key press events when phone is in deep sleep

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to catch Volume Up/Down pressing events when phone is in deep sleep mode. I have read several articles and here what I have done.

In Activities `onCreate` method I set a `WakeLock`

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

I have read that even if my screen is locked if I set this my application will respond to events. Also I have added permission in to Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Then in the `onCreate` method I declare my Broadcast Receiver

```
VolReceiver volumeBroadcastReceiver = new VolReceiver();

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION");
registerReceiver(volumeBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

This all works pretty good then application is in foreground or background, but then I lock my phones screen by pressing on a power button application stop receiving broadcast events, I think that `PowerManager` must solve this issue but it doesn't. So please help me, provide some information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35168869/1293492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to catch Volume Up/Down pressing events when phone is in deep sleep mode.

By definition, that is impossible.

> In Activities onCreate method I set a WakeLock

Then you are not in sleep mode.

> then I lock my phones screen by pressing on a power button application stop receiving broadcast events

There are a few possibilities here. One is that your process was terminated, as it is no longer needed. Once you no longer have any foreground activities, your process is eligible to be terminated to free up memory for other apps, and that can happen at any point. Another possibility is that Android simply does not send that broadcast when the screen is off.

Comment: how I can do that even if battery will die after 5 minutes of work ?

Comment: @ViToBrothers: "So I can't do what I want ?" -- I do not know what you want. "how I can do that even if battery will die after 5 minutes of work ?" -- you are welcome to monitor the battery level and discontinue your `WakeLock` when the battery gets low, I guess. I have no idea if you expect to be having this `WakeLock` acquired for 5 milliseconds, 5 seconds, 5 minutes, 5 hours, 5 days, or 5 geological epochs. Your *user* will want it either to be very short or something they can readily control.

Comment: my last questin. Can I detect volume button presses when phone is locked ?

Comment: @ViToBrothers: I know that the volume buttons *work* when the phone is locked, to change the volume. But that is handled by the OS. My guess is that there is no good way for you to manually handle those events when the phone is locked, but that is just an educated guess.

Comment: I have look to some application like Winamp and they catch volume up and down events when application is in sleep mode ... But why I can't do that may be you know what can I read or look at to do that ? Thanks

Comment: @CommonsWare - sir can this be done by us just the way the OS does it?? Is ndk the way to it ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille Has anyone found out if you can read it with SDK? From past experience, I know that it is possible to receive ACTION_SCREEN_OFF without a WakeLock for long periods of time through a Foreground service. Listening for Volume +/- seems like it should be offered as well, but I cannot find a way

Answer (score 2):

I did pretty much the same thing, but i achieved it by changing the source codes. i have explained that below.

whenever your phone goes to sleep , your **MediaPlaybackService.java** will not listen to keyEvents, but **MediaButtonIntentReceiver.java** will, so receive the intent here of volume up and down, and broadcast an intent and receive it in **MediaPlaybackService.java**, but keep one thing in mind you can't change the UI from here , so you can broadcast another intent from the service and make your **MediaPlaybackActivity.java** receive it , this will change the UI as soon as your screen wakes up.

FYI: when the screen is off, the **PhoneWindowManager.java** queues all the continuous intents and as soon as you release the button it will apply all the intents at once.

Comment: i am talking from the android's source code point of view, and this is not copy pasted. I did the same when i had to add fast forward and rewind functionality to the stock music app when the screen goes off from BT headsets.

Comment: @man_ph Can you bring the example from your own code how you do that and also can you please show the part of code where you receive event from fast forward. Thanks !!! and please modify your answer !!!

Comment: to actually do what i said, one must have the source code of the android image you are using. I am currently not having that code with me, but yeah will upload my answer as soon as i get home.

Comment: yeah , you have to i guess. 
the source code of the image you are using. 
you have to make the changes to the files i have mentioned in my answer.