# Android - Volume Buttons used in application when phone is locked or sleep mode

Tags: java, android

I want to control my android application using volume button which run in phone background all time or not. If i press volume button a certain amount of time (2/3 sec+) in the phone lock or sleep mode then it will work (ex. pressing volume button a certain amount of time in lock/sleep mode it will increase value of a counter and show after open phone or lock).

Android application doing these-
 - application run in phone background or not
 - after pressing volume button a certain amount of time this application will show a toast or message

Is there any way to implement this technique? 
It is possible or not..

Answer (score 3):

check the github: https://github.com/praslnx8/volume_Screen_Lock

They are doing exactly the same.. A service is running to detect the volume button pressing

Solution from that app:
   start media player in the service with volume 0. While media play is on the media buton action will be recieved at reciever even when the phone is locked